# Aptana Studio 3 ftp upload results in server 500 internal server error

Tags: php, ftp, aptana, aptana3

I found two similar issues to this both of which mentioned file permissions. I do not have immediate access to the servers error logs; so, I am trying to derive a solution without them.

This error occurs with an FTP upload of project to server.

File Permissions have been:
instance 1

> ...owner rwe files/folder ...group re files/folder ...others re files/folder (results in 500 error)

instance 2

> owner rwe files/folder group rwe files/folder others rwe files/folder (results in 500 error)

instance 3

> owner files - re folders - r group files - r folders - r others files - r folders - r (results in 500 error)

Upload the same html code from notepad++: file loads without error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

500 error resolved with this: http://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/2388-aptana-studio-3-ftp-transfer-problems

permissions must be r-e for all on file/folders